# Get item name in PayPal payments

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I forward users from my website to the PayPal payment page via a simple POST request that contains payment information:

```
<FORM action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

This form contains everything that is needed including an hidden element "item" that describes the product to be paid. Amazingly in my PayPal backend I never see the value of this "item" field but only the name of the person who paid.

So: what has to be changed to see the item/product name together with the received payments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elmi, the name of the variable for the name of the object is "item_name".
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look: [Paypal variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

> **item_name**
>
> Description of item. If this variable is omitted, buyers enter their
>   own name during checkout.
>
> - Optional for Buy Now, Donate, Subscribe, Automatic Billing, Installment Plan, and Add to Cart buttons
> - Not used with Buy Gift Certificate buttons

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use field name "item_name" instead of "item"